# What preprocessing operations are performed by Tesseract OCR?

Tags: tesseract

I couldn't find a detailed documentation and I don't feel browsing the source code. I want not to redo canny edge detection for example if it is already done by Tesseract engine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This document provides an overview of the engine: https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/docs/blob/master/tesseracticdar2007.pdf

So it looks like you don't need to implement canny edge detection.

Tesseract uses Otsu thresholding to binarize the image before processing it https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/blob/master/ccstruct/otsuthr.h

Edit: If you want to see the binarized image just create a new config file in "\tessdata\configs\", add this line: `tessedit_write_images True` and process your image: `tesseract your_image out your_config_file`. Tesseract saves the binarized image as `tessinput.tif`.

Comment: Where does it save the tessinput.tif file?

Comment: @neoneye @cortex42 In my `\tessdata\configs\` directory, I have a bunch of files, such as `api_config` so when you say create a new config file, do you mean just duplicate an exiting config? How do I open these files in order to add the line you have suggested? Where will I then be able to see the `.tif` file?

Comment: @kiwicomb123 In the home directory