# Does tesseract-ocr perform any image pre-processing?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, ocr, tesseract

I am currently working with the Tesseract OCR engine and I'm using it in conjunction with OpenCV for pre-processing the image before sending it to the OCR engine. However, I was wondering if Tesseract itself is performing some image pre-processing before extracting the text. If so, what are the methods that Tesseract implements?

My objective is to ensure I don't perform redundant pre-processing methods. Some of the pre-processing methods I perform are adaptiveThreshold and GaussianBlur.

Any help/guidance would be much appreciated!

EDIT:
I understand Tesseract does basic image pre-processing. I would like to know if it is possible to bypass these methods and directly feed in an image that I processed manually. (Again, in order to avoid redundant processing on the image)?

Comment: look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27018224/what-preprocessing-operations-are-performed-by-tesseract-ocr/27230986

Comment: Tesseract does some internal image processing. You can check this page to learn more: https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/ImproveQuality

Answer (score 0):

Tesseract uses Leptonica library for doing various pre-processing operations like Otsu binarization algorithm, dilation, erosion and so on.
But because the operations are not dependent to your data, they will cause bad results in some cases.
For more information read [this page](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdoc/blob/master/ImproveQuality.md).